# Regular expression to extract number and string

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to extract some data from a string, the string is something like this `fixed-string-<number>-<string>` . `Fixed string` is always the same, I need to extact number and its string.

In python 3.5, I'm using the next regular expression

```
str = 'initial-string/fixed-string-124-jeff-thompson'
result = re.match('fixed-string-([0-9]*)-(.*)', str)
print (result)
```

But result is always `None` value, I checked the string and it's well formed.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

```
testing = 'first-string/fixed-string-123-jeff-thompson'
pattern = r'fixed-string-(\d+)-(.*)'

result = re.match(pattern, testing)
```

I tested this, and the code still returns me `None`.

Thanks you.

Comment: Do not use `str` as a variable name. Your regex actually works, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/g4r2yC). Note that `re.match` only looks for a match at the string start.

Comment: Please provide an examlple string that you would expect to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using re.match, which tries to match the pattern at the beginning (ie from the first character) of your string. 
Here, "initial-string/" prevents it from matching.

You can either include "initial-string/" in your pattern, or use re.search which will match starting at any position in your string.

Note that it's also better to use raw strings (r'my string with \backslahes') to avoid the potential need for escaping in your pattern.

```
string = 'initial-string/fixed-string-124-jeff-thompson'
result = re.search(r'fixed-string-([0-9]*)-(.*)', str)
result.groups()
# ('124', 'jeff-thompson')
```

or

```
result = re.match(r'initial-string/fixed-string-([0-9]*)-(.*)', str)
result.groups()
# ('124', 'jeff-thompson')
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
> s = 'fixed-string-345-abc'
> re.match(r'fixed-string-(\d+)-(.+)')  # if num and string shouldn't be empty
# re.match(r'fixed-string-(\d*)-(.*)')
> m.group(1, 2)
('345', 'abc')
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, the shorthand classes are Unicode-aware. The `\d` matches more than `[0-9]`. Basically, it is the same regex OP uses, a bit less precise though.

Comment: This code works for me in python console, but not in my code. `re.match` is still returning me `None`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, too:

```
import re
s = 'fixed-string-123-456'
result = re.findall('(?<=fixed-string-)(\d+)-(.*)', s)
if result:
    print (result[0])
#('123', '456')
```

https://ideone.com/4RRwff